# Phonegap 2.9.0 p media, sounds can't be played

Tags: cordova, media

i read few topics about similar issues but non of them solved my problem. So first of all here is the code of index.html

```
<h1>Playing Audio</h1>
    <button onclick="playAudio('sfx/tchp.mp3')">Play Some Audio</button>
    <button onclick="playAudio('sfx/x.wav')">Play Some Audio</button>
    <button onclick="playAudio('tchp.mp3')">Play Some Audio</button>
    <button onclick="playAudio('x.wav')">Play Some Audio</button>

    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script>
        function playAudio(src) {
                src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;

            alert("Zaraz leci media!")

            var media = new Media(src, success, error_error);

            alert("Media sie utworyzli");

            media.play();

            alert("MEdia leca");

        }

        function success() {
            // ignore
        }

        function error_error(e) {
            alert('great error');
            alert(e.message);
        }
    </script>
```

And Config.xml
     plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"

And android manifest

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" 
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

The first alert shows normally, but other 2 don't appear on the screen.

"

Comment: Are you building local (with the CLI) or from build.phonegap.com?

Comment: I'm building using "ant debug" (so proppably local).

Comment: Did you download the plugin source and add it to your project?

Comment: Here is what i did, i downloaded the phonegap 2.9.0 (teacher told us to use this version), i created the project using the windows cmd typing create command. I changed the inside of /assets/www/ and built project using "ant debug".

Comment: I checked the source of cordova.js and media class is there.